# How to change Bootstrap's global default font size?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-size

Bootstrap's global default font-size is 14px, with a line-height of 1.428. How can I change its default global settings?

Will I have to change bootstrap.min.css in all the multiple entries?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are several ways but since you are using just the CSS version and not the SASS or LESS versions, your best bet to use Bootstraps own customization tool:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Customize whatever you want on this page and then you can download a custom build with your own font sizes and anything else you want to change.

Altering the CSS file directly (or simply adding new CSS styles that override the Bootstrap CSS) is not recommended because other Bootstrap styles' values are derived from the base font size. For example:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss#L52

You can see that the base font size is used to calculate the sizes of the h1, h2, h3 etc. If you just changed the font size in the CSS (or added your own overriding font-size) all the other values that used the font size in calculations would no longer be proportionally accurate according to Bootstrap's design.

As I said, your best bet is to just use their own Customize tool. That is exactly what it's for.

If you are using SASS or LESS, you would change the font size in the variables file before compiling.

Comment: How do you combine this customize feature with the npm dependency approach?

Comment: @WouterLievens you can certainly edit the SASS/LESS files and compile them manually if you install Bootstrap via `npm`, `bower`, etc. However I would definitely avoid installing anything via a package manager like `npm` that you expect yourself to customize at all. It's much better to install them manually into your project and commit them to your repo since you are going to customize them. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30058758/proper-way-to-customize-bower-installed-components

Comment: This is specifically for bootstrap 3

Answer (score 83):

Bootstrap uses the variable:

```
$font-size-base: 1rem; // Assumes the browser default, typically 16px
```

I don't recommend mucking with this, but you can.  Best practice is to override the browser default base font size with:

```
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Bootstrap will then take that value and use it via rems to set values for all kinds of things.

Comment: This is in Bootstrap V4 only, because of the change from V3 px measurements to V4 rem measurements, correct?

Comment: @CXJ  you are correct, v3 sets `$font-size-base` as `14px`.  If you are tied to v3, I would recommend changing that value to `1rem`, and then setting `html {font-size: 14px}` as in the example above.

Comment: This is the best way. Bootstrap 4 will magically size like v3 once you change this to 14px. Now to do something about that absurdly bright primary blue color...

Comment: THIS IS THE RIGHT ANSWER. Thank you from the bottom of my heart

Comment: This doesn't work in bootstrap 5 though, at least on me!

Comment: @MattiaRasulo I just tried an upgrade of my app to bs5 and my font setting worked properly.  did you add `html {font-size: 14px;}` in a stylesheet that is being applied to the page?  For example, I have global stylesheet in my app that I try to keep very simple, and in that stylesheet, right at the top, I define the html font size as above.  It's possible, of course, that something else downstream is overriding the font size... in this case, the web inspector is your friend.  Also, try setting something crazy like, `html {font-size: 2px !important;}` just to see that it works.

Comment: @MattiaRasulo Are you using a pre-compiled version of bootstrap in which there are just css files, and no sass files?   In that case, it will be an uphill battle to do overrides, and I don't recommend that path.  The accepted answer on this thread mentioned using Bootstrap's customize tool for downloading compiled css, but I believe that will limit your to version 3.

Comment: No I'm on version 5 and to @CloudMagick I do have it set that way.. it's a bit weird.. that's why I usually just don't use front-end frameworks..

Answer (score 41):

You can add a `style.css`, import this file after the `bootstrap.css` to override this code.

For example:

```
/* bootstrap.css */
* {
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1.428;
}

/* style.css */
* {
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 2;
}
```

Don't change `bootstrap.css` directly for better maintenance of code.

Comment: This is a bad approach. There are a ton of other styles in bootstrap.css that are based on font-size and line-height, e.g. the size of headings. If you just update font-size, nothing else would change. That's why they have a configuration tool. If you update the font-size and line-height in their tool (or in a less config file) all the styles that are based on them will be updated too. Also, when you use their tool, bootstrap gives you a file that you can import into their tool later if you're upgrading bootstrap or decide you want to make changes. Jake's answer is best.

Comment: The `html` option below is better, otherwise tags within other element (e.g. a `p` with a `lead` class) won't have the same font size, giving an inconsistent appearance.

Answer (score 16):

The recommended way to do this from the current v4 docs is:

```
$font-size-base: 0.8rem;
$line-height-base: 1;
```

Be sure to define the variables above the bootstrap css include and they will override the bootstrap.

No need for anything else and this is the cleanest way

It's described quite clearly in the docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/typography/#global-settings

Comment: It doesn't say you need to set `$font-size-base` to `0.8rem` in the documentation.

Answer (score 11):

As of Bootstrap 5 you can set the default font size by changing the $font-size-root variable.

```
$font-size-root: 16px;
```

Answer (score 5):

In v4 change the SASS variable:

```
$font-size-base: 1rem !default;
```

Answer (score 4):

I use Bootstrap via CDN (Content Delivery Network), so I solved it with this easy way. Change the global default `font-size` in the `<html>` tag.

Example for smaller font-size:

```
<html style="font-size:0.875em">
```

Simple change the **em** value.

With Bootstrap Version 5.2 the font size is 1rem:

> font-size-base: 1rem; // Assumes the browser default, typically `16px`

0.875em = 14px, if default browser font size is 16px

1em = 16 px

1.125em = 18px, if default browser font size is 16px

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but this framework keeps evolving.

In Bootstrap v5, you have a new way to reduce the font size via CSS variables.

> Ultimately Bootstrap 5 will continue to see more CSS variables added over time, in order to provide more real-time customization without the need to always recompile Sass. Our approach is to take our source Sass variables and transform them into CSS variables. That way, even if you don’t use CSS variables, you still have all the power of Sass. This is still in-progress and will take time to fully implement.

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/content/reboot/#css-variables

As quoted there is a work in progress, most of these variables are available since v5.2, and some since v5.3, all of them starts with bootstrap prefix (--bs-).

You must set the variable in the body like this:

```
<body style="--bs-body-font-size: 1.25rem">
<!--- ... -->
</body>
```

I strongly suggest to use em or rem as unit.

It's kind of documented, but is not easy to find, these variables are scattered by little parts in all documentation. I never liked the idea of recompile SASS/SCSS, using this approach you can use CDNs as you do with others JS/CSS.

You can find most of those variables inspecting a bootstrap v5.x page, going at the bottom of styles panel. You can use to [my page](https://lyoneel.dev) to see those variables, is running at the time of writing v5.3.

Comment: This isn't "global" - it doesn't change the size of a `legend`, for example. The `$font-size-root` SASS variable turns into `--bs-root-font-size`, which changes everything.

Answer (score -8):

I just solved this type of problem. I was trying to increase

font-size to h4 size. I do not want to use h4 tag. 
I added my css after bootstrap.css it didn't work.
The easiest way is this:
On the HTML doc, type

```
<p class="h4">
```

You do not need to add anything to your css sheet. It works fine
Question is suppose I want a size between h4 and h5?
Answer why? Is this the only way to please your viewers?
I will prefer this method to tampering with standard docs like bootstrap.

Comment: The `h4` class applies more than just a font-size, so this change would have unintended consequences.