# Padding in text field. Twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap. How i can set custom paddings in text fields?

My field looks like this:

[image]

but I want to make field like this:

[image]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make your question more fit for Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use just like

```
input[type="text"] {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use these css

```
input{
padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For better programming pratices create a new css file, put your css code and import after the bootstrap.css file.

See one example at: [How to change Bootstrap's global default font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678542/how-to-change-bootstraps-global-default-font-size/28678715#28678715)