# Why is bootstrap setting the default font-size to 10px?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking at the font-size for the `html` element and it says: 10px.  And it claims that it comes from bootstrap (v3).

[image]

And sure enough, in bootstrap.css, I see the following:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

From what I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678542/how-to-change-bootstraps-global-default-font-size), the default size should be 14px.  The reason I am asking is that I've started using `rem` units and everything is appearing to be very small because the base font size is small.

What am I missing?

Comment: The font-size is 14px on the body: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1084

Comment: i guess to make the math easy

Comment: Like @TemaniAfif said, maybe it's just to easily convert the root size to REM. REM is a multiple of the root size, so if you want 18px on something, you can easily use 1.8rem--rather than having to do e.g. 14px * 1.2rem and figuring out which rem is correct by calculation.

Comment: It seems like a dumb thing for Bootstrap to set the font-size to something static like that. Because then the user can't resize the text according to browser settings. And also, even if you override that to an REM equaling 10px, the resizing will still be much smaller than usual for browser settings (since standard is 16px).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bootstrap version 3.3.7 there is a style:

```
html {
  font-size: 10px;
   ...
}
```

Change to: (or whatever value you would like)

```
html {
    font-size: 100%;
    ...
}
```

Comment: 3.3.7 has `font-size: 10px;` https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css