# Zoom Client-side - JHipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

**Tools**

Using Jhipster v5.0.1 and Angular v6.0.0

**Goal**

For my uses, the zoom is too high (or conversely that the global font size is too high) using the native default JHipster parameters. However, all proportions are clean and nice. When I adjust the zoom of the screen (75%) everything is just as I would like. Is there any way to  use 75% zoom by default? Or to decrease everything at once? Without affecting one by one each element?

I don't have a clue to do that for now.

Thanks,

Manuela

Comment: Are you speaking only of font size or also of images? Have you tried just changing the font-size in CSS?

Comment: What I did is to change the css in global.css using body { font-size = 80 %;} I don't know if it's a good practice but it's the only thing I could find. However, I have to do it also for the .dropdown-menu and still, it doesn't change the font-size of the first interface. I wonder if there is a way to change everything at the same time... Thanks!

Comment: This is related to Bootstrap 4 customization not JHipster specifically, you should tag the question accordingly. Anyway, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678542/how-to-change-bootstraps-global-default-font-size even though some answers are for BS 3 not BS 4 you should also consider using the SASS option of JHipster for easier customization of Bootstrap

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the project I work on hasn't JHipster SASS option activated unfortunately. I will look to this link. Thanks again.